# Selecting a subclass from a set of subclasses to be used the in the main program, using a command line input parameter

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a way to call a generic subclass in the main program, where the specific subclasses that can be chosen from can have unique input arguments.

I have a main program, main.py, that compares the results of a given test to the results of a basic model. The different tests are subclasses stored in the module tests.py. I'm trying to work out the best way to call any given test (subclass) in main.py by providing a command line input parameter. (Each subclass can have a different number of arguments, and some are supplied by a config file.)

My current approach works, but it feels clunky and like there should be a better way:

1. In the main program, main.py, I use a dictionary to select the subclass I want:

   `test_case = tests.select_subclass(case)` (example of function below)

where

`tests.py` is the module holding the various subclasses, and the function *select_subclass*;
`case` is provided as an input parameter in the command line

2. I use `eval` to initialize the given test case:

   `test = eval(test_case)`
3. and then use a run function in the given subclass to run the function as needed:

   `test.run(x, y)`

where `x` and `y` are the two variables that are required in the run function of each subclass.

In `tests.py`,

```
def select_subclass(key): 

    subclss_dict = {
            ‘Test1’: ‘tests.Test1(in1, in2)’
            ‘Test2’: ‘tests.Test2(config.getint(“test2”, “intvar1”),' 
                     'config.getint(“test2”, “intvar2”), in1, in2)’
            ‘Test3’: ‘tests.Test3(config.get(“test3”, “var1”),' 
                     'config.getint(“test3”, “intvar”),'          
                     'config.get(“test3”, “var2”), in1, in2)’
                      }
```

where input variables for some subclasses are being read from an ini config file.

I'm using python 2.7

I’m still getting used to effectively using classes, and any suggestions on how to do this in a cleaner/better way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing this with a colleague, he suggested a way of doing this that is cleaner and easier:

1. Make the subclasses modular: tests.py will only hold the base class. Each subclass will be its own module (and import tests so the base class will be inherited).
2. Dynamically import the test module into main.py:

   ```
   try:
       test_mod = __import__(case) 
   except ImportError:
       # exit program if import fails
       raise SystemExit
   ```
3. Instantiate the instance:

   ```
   ctest = getattr(test_mod, case)
   # in1, in2 will be used in every subclass and are global variables
   a_test = test(in1, in2)
   a_test.get_input(config)
   ```

where `get_input()` is a function in each subclass that grabs the necessary input parameters for the given test case:

(for example, for Test2 subclass)

```
    def get_input(self, config):
        self.intvar1 = config.getint("test2", "intvar1")
        self.intvar2 = config.getint("test2", "intvar2")
```

and `config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()`